# Data updated in FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT not send back to controller

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am working with Symfony 2.7 and have created a custom FormType based on Symfonys `EntityType`. Within the FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT of this type I update the received data by adding a special entity. However this chance is not send back to the controller:

**Action within controller:**

```
public function customEditAction(Request $request) {
    $formData = $this->getFormData();
    // formData has a property myEntities which is array of MyEntity

    $form = $this->createForm('my_form_type', $formData);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        foreach ($formData->getMyEntities() as $myEntity)
            dump($myEntity);
    }

    ...
}
```

**my_form_type**

```
class MyFormType extends AbstractType {
    ...

    public function getName() {
        return 'my_form_type';
    }  

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->add('myEntities', 'my_entities_type', array(
                ...
            ),   
        ));

        ...
    }
}
```

**my_entities_type**

```
class MyEntitiesType extends AbstractType {
    ...
    public function getParent() {
        return 'entity';
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'my_entities_type';
    }  

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options) { 
        ...
    }  

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) use ($options) {
            // Update data with a special entity.
            $data = $event->getData();

            $specialEntity = $this->getSomeSpecialEntity();
            $data[] = $specialEntity;

            // Dump shows, that the entiy was correctly added to $data
            foreach ($data as $myEntity)
                dump($myEntity);

            $event->setData($data);
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

**Expected Result**:

1. Form is created with some set of entities within `$formData->getMyEntities()`
2. Form is presented to the user. `EntityType` (parent of `MyEntitiesType`) fetched all available Entities to build a selection. Entities within `$formData->getMyEntities()` are pre-selected
3. User makes his choice and selects a new set of Entities, e.g. `Entity1` and `Entity2`
4. Form is submitted
5. In `FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT` `$specialEntity` is added to the data/selection
6. **Both dumps (within `POST_SUBMIT` and within the controller) should show the selected entities including $specialEntity**

**Everything works fine beside step 6:** While the dump within `POST_SUBMIT` shows that `$specialEntity` is in $data, the dump within the controller only shows the user selected entities...

Why isn't the changed data submitted back to the controller? What do I have to do, to get the updated data to the controller?

**EDIT:**

Adding the special entity in `FormEvents::SUBMIT` does not work, since this entity is not managed and will thus result in an exception within the `EntityType` implementation.

Comment: move `$formData = $this->getFormData();` after/inside `if ($form->isValid()) {` and remove the argument from `$this->createForm('my_form_type', $formData);`

Comment: `$this->getFormData()` has nothing to do with `$form->getData()`. It is just a custom function to load the object `$formData` that is passed as data to the form. It could also be renamed to `$this->getMyCustomFormData()` or anything else. How should I create the form with this data, if I call this function after the form was created?

Comment: UPDATE: Explicitly using `$formData = $form->getData()` within `if ($form->isValid())` does not change anything.